# Can I call inherited parent method without a name in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance

Is there a way to call an inherited method, without specifying it's function name?

Something like:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    function some_function(){
        // magically inherit without naming the parent function
        // it will call parent::some_function()
        parent::inherit();

        // other code
    }

    function another_function(){
        // it will call parent::another_function()
        $result = parent::inherit();

        // other code
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I could think of a hack to do this using `debug_backtrace()`, get the last function where inherit() was called and access it's parent with the same function name. I was wondering if there's a nicer way instead of using debug functions which are clearly not meant for this.

Comment: May I ask WHY you need to do this?

Comment: Sure. I don't have a limitation or a very "pure" reason, I just find it superfluous to repeat the method name, especially when this might be long, and is also arbitrary (chosen by developer, which might be a bad speller and mistype, etc). 

I find it more natural to just "inherit()" it, like you do in many other languages. It's also a bit easier when you change the method name, you don't have to change it twice for each child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [magic `__FUNCTION__` constant.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
class A 
{
    function some_function()
    {
        echo 'called ' . __METHOD__;
    }
}

class B extends A 
{
    function some_function()
    {
        call_user_func(array('parent', __FUNCTION__));           
    }
}

 $b = new B;
 $b->some_function(); // prints "called A::some_function"
```

Instead of

```
call_user_func(array('parent', __FUNCTION__));
```

you can also do

```
parent::{__FUNCTION__}();
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. I accepted your answer, though I find it just as "misleading" as my original option, from a debug point-of-view. Such code is difficult to debug and will probably cause more trouble on the long run than it solves. Nevertheless, it's a good answer. Thanks!

Comment: @George Thanks, but how is it difficult to debug? `parent::{__FUNCTION__}();` is the same as writing `parent::some_function()` just that PHP put the method name for you. How is that much different from writing `inherit()` or `super()`?

Comment: I'm thinking that in an environment where multiple devs work on the same code, at some point you get very tired of these "magic" enhancements with PHP. Calling methods that don't exist, magic constants, magic getters and setters, etc, they're all difficult to debug through a simple visual inspection of the code and can be misleading - most of the time you have to run the code and see what the constants are holding. I'm talking here about a general approach, not this particular instance, which is fairly readable as you put it `parent::{__FUNCTION__}()`, which is why I accepted it.

Comment: @George well, agreed. Magic is always hard to see through. Though with the magic constants it's really just that PHP replaces them when it parses the class, so they are very predictable because they don't depend on runtime information. Unlike magic methods, which indeed require you to know the current state of execution.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty, but:

```
class Adult {
    function mummy(){
        return 'Walk like an Egyptian';
    }

    function daddy(){
        return 'Luke, I am your father';
    }
}


class Child extends Adult {
    function mummy(){
        echo 'Mummy says: ';
        $me = explode('::',__METHOD__)[1];
        echo parent::$me();
    }

    function daddy(){
        echo 'Daddy says: ';
        $me = explode('::',__METHOD__)[1];
        echo parent::$me();
    }
}

$o = new Child();
$o->mummy();
$o->daddy();
```

**EDIT**

Actually giving you a parent method called inherit();

```
class Adult {
    private function mummy(){
        return 'Walk like an Egyptian';
    }

    private function daddy(){
        return 'Luke, I am your father';
    }

    protected function inherit($method) {
        $beneficiary = explode('::', $method)[1];
        return $this->$beneficiary();
    }
}


class Child extends Adult {
    public function mummy() {
        echo 'Mummy says: ', 
            parent::inherit(__METHOD__), 
            PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function daddy() {
        echo 'Daddy says: ', 
            parent::inherit(__METHOD__), 
            PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$o = new Child();
$o->mummy();
$o->daddy();
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, your answer is very similar with @Gordon above, but I accepted his since it was first. Your answer also adds a minor (highly unlikely) possible bug by assuming the `explode(__METHOD__)` function would return an array with at least two entries, which is not a safe assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically calling functions:

```
static::$functionName();
```

In your case:

```
$func = __FUNCTION__;
parent::$func();
```

Note: the function name must be a string, if it's the actual function (not really relevant in this context) then it first needs to be converted to its string name first.

---

Other stuff that your question will probably lead you towards in the long run.

Check out [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) it's what you're looking for.

Example taken from the linked page.

```
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function test() {
        static::who(); // Here comes Late Static Bindings
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

B::test();
```

---

Comment: I think the point is to call parent::some_function() without having to put some_function(). Not sure LSB will help here.

Comment: @Gordon Ok, I've extended the answer to cover dynamic calls.

Comment: Thanks, but that's still not what the OP wants. He doesn't know how to get $functionName in the first place and static::$foo() will not call the parent.

Comment: Ok, I'll revoke the downvote although you left the irrelvant stuff in your question.

Comment: I've left it in because it appears OP is unintentionally defeating the purpose of static methods and inherited classes.

Comment: I don't think I'm defeating any purpose regarding static methods or inheriting. I haven't had any reference to static methods in my question at all. I was curious whether there was a cleaner way of inheriting a function without typing it's name again - I find it superfluous and it adds no value to the code.

Comment: Moreso, calling `parent::func()` is not even inheritance, it's only a call to an arbitrary function where `parent` is a magic keyword for the current class parent.

Comment: The point I'm attempting to make is that it's a ridiculous idea to declare a duplicate function in the inherited class (extend means inherit - although you mean, the methods are static). Parent - as of late static binding - is the context, if in both A and B you'd declared public static $shoe, parent would read from A whereas static would read from B